# Compare 3 values within certain percentage of each other

Tags: javascript, comparison

I am trying to make this:

1. 3 input boxes
2. take the value of the input and compare to a certain percentage

if values are within 3% of each other. output = something
else output something else.

any help would be appreciated on getting started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create the inputs which on a basic level looks like this:

```
<input type="text" width="3em">
```

That will create a single input tag. So, placing three, or however many, will create the inputs. Now, we need a way to get the inputs we just created. To do this we'll need some JavaScript.

```
document.getElementsByTagName("input");
```

This will get us all input tags on the screen. Now, we can iterator through these tags and get the data we need in which I will place into an array.

Note: Each input tag has a property called value which stores the string placed inside of the input which can be changed to a number by placing a `+` in front.

```
var numbers = [],
    inputs  = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i)
{
    var number = +inputs[i].value;
    // Makes sure that a number is there.
    if(!isNaN(number))
        numbers.push(number);
}
```

Now that we have everything in an array, time for some math!

---

Let us look at an easy example of comparing the percentage off a particular number is from another. If we are given 7 and 3 how far off are they from each other? First we find the average -> `(7 + 3) / 2` then we find the difference between `|3 - 7|` then we divide the difference by the average ... `4 / 5 = .8`. Yay! But, what about three numbers? Well, now we must do that between every number... Then we check each one to see if within range. Yuck! To do this it will require an embedded for loop.

So, we need to have an embedded for loop such that we do not repeat comparisons. Just like the following:

`numbers => 1  2  3  4`

`Compare 1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 1 -> 4`

`Compare 2 -> 3, 2 -> 4`

`Compare 3 -> 4`

`Stop!`

This brought me to this mess:

```
var inrange   = true,
    tolerance = 3/*In percentage!*/;
for(var i = 0; i < numbers.length && inrange; ++i)
    for(var j = i + 1; j < numbers.length && inrange; ++j)
    {
        var diff = (numbers[i] - numbers[j]),
        // Need to make sure diff is positive. Could use Math.abs...
        pdiff    = 2 * (diff < 0 ? -1*diff : diff) 
                 / (numbers[i] + numbers[j]);
        // If false will cause the loops to stop.
        inrange = (100 * pdiff) <= tolerance;
    }
```

With the calculation function we can now focus on the display!

---

Now, we need a button that will call to a function and do the magic for us! This can be done with the input tag as well, but by changing its type.

```
<input type="submit" value="calculate" onclick="calculate()">
```

So, now we need a way to display... A really easy way is to have a `<p>` tag with an id.

```
<p id="display"></p>
```

To get this tag, we can use some JavaScript as well.

```
document.getElementById("display");
```

These tags have an attribute called `innerHTML` in which we can edit to do, well..., change the inner HTML.

```
var p = document.getElementById("display");
p.innerHTML = "Hello World!";
```

---

Now, we can combine everything above to get:

```html
<input type="text" width="3em">
<input type="text" width="3em">
<input type="text" width="3em">
<input type="submit" value="calculate" onclick="calculate()">
<p id="display"></p>
<p id="results"></p>

<script>
// The tolerance for the numbers to be within.
    var tolerance = 3,
    // The number of inputs expected.
        amount    = 3;

    function calculate() {
        var numbers = [],
            inputs  = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
        
        // Gets all of the numbers.
        for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i) 
        // Need to check type to make sure not getting the button.
            if(inputs[i].type === "text"){
            var number = +inputs[i].value;
            if(!isNaN(number))
                numbers.push(number);
        }

        // Need to make sure the correct amount of inputs were found.
        if(numbers.length !== amount) return;

        var inrange = true,
        // Gets the results p tag.
            results  = document.getElementById("results");
        // Clear old results.
        results.innerHTML = "";

        // Compares each number finding the avg percent difference.
        for(var i = 0; i < numbers.length && inrange; ++i)
            for(var j = i + 1; j < numbers.length && inrange; ++j) {
                var diff  = (numbers[i] - numbers[j]),
                    pdiff = 2 * (diff < 0 ? -1*diff : diff)
                         / (numbers[i] + numbers[j]);
                inrange = (100 * pdiff) <= tolerance;
                results.innerHTML += "Input " + (i+1) + " to " + (j+1)
                                  +  ": " + (100 * pdiff) + " " + (inrange ? "<=" : ">") + " " + tolerance
                                  +  " <br>";
            }

        // Gets the display tag.
        var p = document.getElementById("display");

        // Makes sure that within tolerance!
        if(inrange) 
            p.innerHTML = "Within tolerance!";
        else
            p.innerHTML = "Try again...";
    }
</script>
```

---

A function I use to limit the amount of digits shown where `x` is the number and `n` is the number of digits. This can be used on the display of the results. To use, simply take the `results.innerHTML += ... + (100 * pdiff) + ...` and place the function `results.innerHTML += ... + limit_decimal(100 * pdiff, #) + ...` where `#` is the number of decimals you want.

```
function limit_decimal(x, n) {
    // Makes sure it is a number.
    if(isNaN(x = +x)) return x;
    // If n is not a number then set to zero.
    isNaN(n = +n) && (n = 0);
    // Makes x a string.
    var s = x + "",
    // Split the string up by the decimal.
        parts = s.split(".");
    // Return the first part if n is zero.
    if(n === 0) return parts[0];
    // If just the first part, place zeros.
    if(parts.length === 1)
    {
        s += ".";
        for(var i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            s += "0";
        return s;
    }
    // If not, then get the length.
    var l = parts[1].length;
    // If the length is larger than n, remove those.
    if(l >= n)
    {
        return parts[0] + "." + parts[1].slice(0,n);
    }
    // Else, add zeros to fit the length.
    for(var i = 0; i < n - l; ++i)
        s+="0";
    return s;
}
```

Comment: how can I expand on this to document.write(" ") the difference in percentage between the 3 numbers?

Comment: Does that edit help? Sorry, there may be a bug in it. I tried to do this from my phone lol. I prefer not to use `document.write("")` because it writes over the current HTML page:)

Comment: Seems to work good,  I just need to truncate or chop the output so the values aren't so long...

Comment: Hmm... I updated it to show the results a little nicer. Now, how it currently is set up it will show all results up to the one that was not within tolerance. To fix that, remove the `&& inrange` in the for loops and replace `inrange = (100 * pdiff) <= tolerance;` with `inrange = inrange && ((100 * pdiff) <= tolerance);`.

Comment: To round, look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round). It can be a little tricky. I added a function I usually use in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code sample you can derive the logic from.

https://jsfiddle.net/1u4c0jzj/

```
<input type="text" id="value1" />
<input type="text" id="value2" />
<input type="text" id="value3" />
<button id="checkValues">Check</button>
<div id="output" />


document.getElementById("checkValues").onclick = function(){
    var value1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("value1").value);
    var value2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("value2").value);
    var value3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("value3").value);    
    var maxValue = parseFloat(Math.max(Math.max(value1, value2), value3));

    if(1-(value1 / maxValue) <= .03 && 1-(value2 / maxValue) <= .03 && 1-(value3 / maxValue) <= .03){
     alert('all numbers are within 3% of each other')   
    }
    else{
     alert('numbers NOT within 3%');   
    }
}
```

It takes in 3 inputs, finds the max and ensures that all 3 numbers are within 3% of the max.

Answer (score 0):

Just sort the values and calculate the [relative change](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_change_and_difference):

```js
function calculatePercent(a, b, c) {
    var values = [a, b, c];
    values.sort(function (a, b) { return a - b; });
    return (values[2] - values[0]) / values[0];
}
document.write(calculatePercent(100, 101, 102) + '<br>');
document.write(calculatePercent(80, 90, 100) + '<br>');
```